# Beginner prolog programming

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to learn prolog. I want to write in prolog a code for a general list of numbers. So far I have `pick_numbers_general(List, N, NumList)`, where `List` is a general list (including nested ones), and `N` is a number.

The predicate succeeds if `NumList` is a list of the numbers in `List`, including those in nested lists, greater than `N`. The appearance order of the 
numbers in `Numlist` is the same as that in `L`, so for instance, `pick_numbers_general([g,h,1,[2,[n,3]],p],1,NumList)` is true when `NumList` is `[2,3]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: you're doing three operations at once. If you split those out, this exercises becomes a lot easier.

```
pick_numbers_general(List, Min, Numbers) :-
    flatten(List, Flat),
    filter_numbers(Flat, Numbers0),
    filter_greater_than(Numbers0, Min, Numbers).
```